# can't stream with python-binance

Tags: python, websocket, pycharm, binance

I try to do a simple stream on some lines but I get an error message. I could notice that depending on the version the websocket call is different.
I am in version Python-binance 1.0.15

could you help me?

```
# Importing libraries
from binance.client import Client
import configparser
from binance.streams import ThreadedWebsocketManager


# Loading keys from config file
config = configparser.ConfigParser()
config.read_file(open('secret.cfg'))
actual_api_key = config.get('BINANCE', 'ACTUAL_API_KEY')
actual_secret_key = config.get('BINANCE', 'ACTUAL_SECRET_KEY')

client = Client(actual_api_key, actual_secret_key, tld="com")


def stream_data(msg):
    """
    Function to process the received messages
    param msg: input message
    """
    print(f"message type: {msg['e']}")
    print(f"close price: {msg['c']}")
    print(f"best ask price: {msg['a']}")
    print(f"best bid price: {msg['b']}")
    print("---------------------------")


# Starting the WebSocket
twm = ThreadedWebsocketManager()
twm.start()

#Subscribe to the stream
twm.start_symbol_miniticker_socket(callback=stream_data, symbol="BTCUSDT")

# Stopping websocket
twm.stop()
```

Here the error message :

CANCEL read_loop

Process finished with exit code 0

Answer (score 1):

The following parts shall be addressed:

- ThreadedWebsocketManager shall be initialized with API Key/Secret
- client call is not required in this scenario
- after starting the streaming, you should join twm where the streaming happens

```
# Importing libraries
from binance.client import Client
import configparser
from binance.streams import ThreadedWebsocketManager

# Loading keys from config file
config = configparser.ConfigParser()
config.read_file(open('secret.cfg'))
actual_api_key = config.get('BINANCE', 'ACTUAL_API_KEY')
actual_secret_key = config.get('BINANCE', 'ACTUAL_SECRET_KEY')

# This is not REQUIRED
# client = Client(actual_api_key, actual_secret_key, tld="com")


def stream_data(msg):
    """
    Function to process the received messages
    param msg: input message
    """
    print(f"message type: {msg['e']}")
    print(f"close price: {msg['c']}")
    print(f"best ask price: {msg['a']}")
    print(f"best bid price: {msg['b']}")
    print("---------------------------")


# Starting the WebSocket
twm = ThreadedWebsocketManager(api_key=actual_api_key, api_secret=actual_secret_key)
twm.start()

# Define a stream or two
streams = ['ethusdt@kline_1m', 'btcusdt@kline_1m']

# Starting Binance multiplex_socket on ThreadedWebsocketManager
twm.start_multiplex_socket(callback=stream_data, streams=streams)

timeout = 0.1 # seconds
while True and twm.is_alive():
    twm.join(timeout=timeout) # Give twm a call to process the streaming
    # Do other stuff here

# Stopping websocket
twm.stop()
```